# Application.CutCopyMode = 0 when performing a cut?

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a macro to try to disable the ability for users to copy and paste into my nicely created entry sheet by converting their attempts into Paste Values only.  I was getting reports that this macro wasn't always doing its job and it seemed obvious to me that was because i was only watching out for "xlCopy" and not "xlCut" too.

I altered the code to this into account but the results were horrific.  Now what was happening when the user did a cut (i was testing with Ctrl+X), the debug mode was showing that Application.CutCopyMode = 0.   Even worse whenever I then did an undo (Ctrl+Z), thats when the debug showed Application.CutCopyMode = 2  (xlCut = 2, xlCopy = 1, else = 0).

Any ideas what could be the problem?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Me.ProtectContents = True And Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Then  '' Only prevent if sheet is protected and user is copying.
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        Target.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think what you're seeing makes sense, though I can't test it now. A cut can only have one paste, so by the time the change event fires, the mode is back to zero. Another issue will be you can't do Paste Special after a Cut.

Comment: Interesting.  What would be your suggestion at catching the Cut before it happens and converting it to Paste Special to maintain formatting?

Comment: I don't really have a suggestion. I've never implemented something that does that, and it's not a trivial problem. I think the more common approach is to disable Cutting altogether, but I haven't done that either.